# How to count multidimensional object? (php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-collection

I have a Laravel Collection value returned below:

[image]

My question is how to count the total no. of data contained each. Like the example above I must have a result value of 9 with that example.

I tried the below code:

```
array_count_values($jobs)
```

But as expected it returns an error:

> array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

---

Someone knows how to achieve this either in native php way or laravel collection methods?

Comment: `count($jobs);`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver I suppose this will give 4, as count of first level items.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I mean count all the second level. like the example above. thanks for reply Sir.

Comment: Yes, the arrows were throwing me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You have `Collection` instance you can use

`$jobs->collapse()->count()`